# servresolv.conf become blank when system is running

Tags: dns, dhcp, audit, openrc

I use dhcpcd to manage this file.

First, start dhcpcd service, and the file has something with `namesever`.

All things can be done correctly.

But this file will become blank after a while.

I try to use `auditd` to monitor that file.

The report is only about `chmod` and `dhcpcd-run-hook`.

I try to use `resolv.conf.head`. Sometimes it can work, but sometimes `resolv.conf` also become blank.

Is there a way to find more infomation about it? Or do you have any idea to fix this?

Edit:

System: Gentoo/Linux

Initscript: Openrc

I asked on irc, and get a answer: conflicted between different tools. But I only use dhcpcd and Netifrc.

Comment: Witch OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fixed when adding  `modules="dhcpcd"` into `/etc/conf.d/net`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to change attributes on file after you have edited it. So nobody can change the file.

```
chattr +i /etc/resolv.conf
```

Working on Linux file system.
But it isn't real fix, just workaround